# Android Support Material Design Libraries in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an app using Android Studio and AppCompat.  I cannot seem to compile the Android support library to make a TabLayout.  I get the error

```
"Could not find com.android.support:design:23.2.0".
```

Comment: The most recent version of the library is 23.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure latest version matches `targetSdkVersion`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the package in the Gradle file? 
You need to have the Android Support Repository via the SDK manager.

Comment: Yes I have installed all the packages that are required.

Comment: Make sure you are using compile and target sdk the latest one.